# How to make jest only run testing for the files in src folder Angular?

Tags: angular, jestjs, ts-jest, jest-preset-angular

I am learning how to setup jest testing in angular. I follow the instruction of [jest-preset-angular](https://thymikee.github.io/jest-preset-angular/docs/getting-started/installation).

I can successfully make the jest run in angular, but my app also has two submodules in the root, which `jest` gives a lot of errors on that. I would like to avoid that for now.

**I wonder how to set up configuration for `jest` or `jest-preset-angular` to only run testing in `src` folder?**

---

I have two files regarding the jest setup in the `<rootDir>`:

```
# jest.config.js
module.exports = {
  preset: 'jest-preset-angular',
  setupFilesAfterEnv: ['<rootDir>/setup-jest.ts'],
};
```

```
# setup-jest.ts
import 'jest-preset-angular/setup-jest';
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can set the roots property in the jest.config.js to any directory you want. The example below only runs tests that are under /src/test/

```
module.exports = {
  preset: 'jest-preset-angular',
  roots: ['<rootDir>/src/test/']
};
```

Comment: Wow, that is an easy fix. Do I need to change anything for `setupFilesAfterEnv: ['<rootDir>/setup-jest.ts']` or move `setup-jest.ts` into `src`?

Comment: No, only if you want to move that file aswell.